# How to insert data into MongoDB (Python, Pymongo)

Tags: python, database, mongodb, dictionary, pymongo

So i know that in pymongo we create dictionaries to represent documents.

Here is the data I need to store into mongodb

"Dog Snails Zebra Horse Fox".split()

Pet    = [Dog,        Snails,   Fox,          Horse,       Zebra     ]

^^ How would I go about converting either of these into a dictionary so I can store the data in mongoDB?

As I know you have to have the format

emp_rec1 = {
"_id": 1
"name":"Mr.Geek",
"eid":24,
}

But as I only have one key (pets) and many values (dogs, cats, snails, Fox, Horse, Zebra) how would I do this?

Comment: you  want separate record for each pet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MongoDB, data is stored as documents. These documents are stored in MongoDB in JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) format. So you can insert as {
"pet":[
"Dog",
"Snails",
"Fox",
"Horse",
"Zebra"
]
}